# Firebas Firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm working on a project on react and this is my first time using firebase.
I have set up my firebase config file in my app. I keep getting an error message (shown  below) when I import db from my firebase.config.js file.

error message:
export 'getFireStore' (imported as 'getFireStore') was not found in
'firebase/firestore'

my code:

```
enter code here

import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app'
import { getFireStore } from 'firebase/firestore'

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
const firebaseConfig = {
// ...
}

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
export const db = getFireStore()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2EhhV.png)

Comment: I just tried import { getFireStore } from 'firebase/firebase-firestore'
 and the error I got is:

Module not found: Error: Package path ./firebase-firestore is not exported from package /home/emmanuel/house-marketplace/node_modules/firebase

Comment: Which version of firebase are you using ?

Comment: I am using Version 9.8.3

Comment: The function is named `getFirestore`, not `getFireStore` (note the difference in casing).

Comment: The error has been resolved. I misspelled the getFirestore function name. @FrankvanPuffelen pointed this out to me. Thank you very much  Frank Van Puffelen and everybody that contributed.

Answer (score 0):

```
import firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/firestore";
import "firebase/auth";

firebase.initializeApp({

});

const auth = firebase.auth();
const firestore = firebase.firestore();

export { auth, firestore };
```

TRY THIS CODE

Answer (score 0):

did you install the package firebase using

```
npm install firebase
```

Comment: yes. I install firebase using npm. 
The error was a result of misspelling the getFirestore function.